# How to use dynamic parameters ? in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

I need to use two system stored procedures `sp_msforeachtable` and `sp_MSforeachdb` to get size and rows number of each table in each database of a SQL Server instance.

This is the script I use :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #SpaceUsed

CREATE TABLE #SpaceUsed 
(
   TableName sysname
   ,NumRows BIGINT
   ,ReservedSpace VARCHAR(50)
   ,DataSpace VARCHAR(50)
   ,IndexSize VARCHAR(50)
   ,UnusedSpace VARCHAR(50)
) 

DECLARE @str VARCHAR(500)
SET @str =  'exec sp_spaceused ''?'''

INSERT INTO #SpaceUsed 
    EXEC sp_msforeachtable @str

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SpaceUsed_to_export_to_drop

SELECT 
   DB_NAME() Databse_name,
   TableName, 
   NumRows, 
   CONVERT(numeric(18,2),REPLACE(ReservedSpace,' KB','')) / 1000 as ReservedSpace_MB,
   CONVERT(numeric(18,2),REPLACE(DataSpace,' KB','')) / 1000 as DataSpace_MB,
   CONVERT(numeric(18,2),REPLACE(IndexSize,' KB','')) / 1000 as IndexSpace_MB,
   CONVERT(numeric(18,2),REPLACE(UnusedSpace,' KB','')) / 1000 as UnusedSpace_MB
INTO
    SpaceUsed_to_export_to_drop
FROM 
    #SpaceUsed
ORDER BY 
    TableName ASC, ReservedSpace_MB DESC;
```

This returns details for each table; I need to add `sp_MSforeachdb`.

I set up this :

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb '

   CREATE TABLE #SpaceUsed (
   TableName sysname
   ,NumRows BIGINT
   ,ReservedSpace VARCHAR(50)
   ,DataSpace VARCHAR(50)
   ,IndexSize VARCHAR(50)
   ,UnusedSpace VARCHAR(50)
   ) 

   DECLARE @str VARCHAR(500)
   INSERT INTO #SpaceUsed 
   EXEC sp_msforeachtable ''exec sp_spaceused ''?''''

   drop table if exists SpaceUsed_to_export_to_drop
   SELECT 
   DB_NAME() Databse_name,
   TableName, 
   NumRows, 
   CONVERT(numeric(18,2),REPLACE(ReservedSpace,'' KB'','''')) / 1000 as ReservedSpace_MB,
   CONVERT(numeric(18,2),REPLACE(DataSpace,'' KB'','''')) / 1000 as DataSpace_MB,
   CONVERT(numeric(18,2),REPLACE(IndexSize,'' KB'','''')) / 1000 as IndexSpace_MB,
   CONVERT(numeric(18,2),REPLACE(UnusedSpace,'' KB'','''')) / 1000 as UnusedSpace_MB
   into SpaceUsed_to_export_to_drop
   FROM #SpaceUsed
   ORDER BY TableName asc,ReservedSpace_MB desc

   select * from SpaceUsed_to_export_to_drop
   ORDER BY TableName asc,ReservedSpace_MB desc'
```

But I get the following errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
>   Incorrect syntax near 'master'
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
>   Incorrect syntax near 'tempdb'

which means that the parameter *?* is getting database name but not the table name.

How can I use the parameter *?* to refer to the table names - but not the database names - please?

Comment: `?` is going to be first replaced by `sp_MSforeachdb` first, meaning that `?` won't be the for replacement by `sp_MSforeachtable`. Also, your statement for `sp_MSforeachdb` is lacking  a `USE ?;`, so that means that'll be run against the same database (`master`) each time.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks, actually that's my question: how can I use both procedures to get information for each table of every database ? In other words how can I use the "?" more than one time in the same scope ?